# Jquery Slider keep scrolling right clicking next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I stop my slider to keep scrolling? Its something to do with the offset? 
I can't figure it out. 
Any help much appreciated.

```
var $container = $(container);

var resizeFn = function () {
    var small = $(window).width() < 800;
    $container.toggleClass('four', small).toggleClass('six', !small);
}

var toggleButtons = function () {

}

var nextPane = function (e) {
    e && e.preventDefault();
    var $container = $(this).closest('.grid-container');
    var $items = $('.items', $container);
    var offset = $items.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
    var width = $container.width() + parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', ''));
    $items.css('marginLeft', offset - width);
}

var prevPane = function (e) {
    e && e.preventDefault();
    var $container = $(this).closest('.grid-container');
    var $items = $('.items', $container);
    var offset = $items.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
    var width = $container.width() + parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', '')); 
    $items.css('marginLeft', offset + width);
}

resizeFn();
$(window).resize(resizeFn);

$('.next', $container).click(nextPane);
$('.prev', $container).click(prevPane);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqzA6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
var width = $('.item').width() + parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', ''));
```

instead of `$container.width()`
in both `var nextPane = function (e) {`  and `var prevPane = function (e) {`
and it works fine

Comment: doesn't work like this. Could you please look at it?

Comment: yes i mean you need to use, $('.item') instead of $container if you liked my answer please accept it as correct thanx:)

Comment: yes, like that doesn't work. its scrolling in a wrong way. could check? http://jsfiddle.net/nqzA6/1/ should calculate the width of the container(items)

Comment: happy to accept your answer if you help me to solve my question

Comment: sorry i thought that was what you wanted so you need something like this: $items.css('marginLeft', offset + (width*4));   ??

Comment: could u try to put together a fiddle as doen't work like you said in both ways? it calculates the width of the container and scrolls right clicking next. But if the images are finished it should stop

Comment: No as I'm not seen the last three items(images) it should scroll until the last one without keep scrolling. then going back like normal not the the first one.

Comment: how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/nqzA6/6/   i fixed the issue with the previous button. you should wait for the effects to take place before clicking. i dont get why you dont see the images. it shows from box 1 - 15 and then stops

Comment: images are 21, and is broken now as the prev buttons keeps scrolling left

Comment: you had another error in width items so i put it in 4400% width http://jsfiddle.net/nqzA6/8/   note that you have to wait for the effect to complete each time or else it will mess up the margins

Comment: do you know how to prevent this margin issue?